# How to show 00:00 (24hrs format) for 12am instead 24:00 in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime-format

I need to show current time in 24-hours format in my Flutter project. Everything works perfect except that it will show 24:00 for 12am instead of showing 00:00. How can I solve this?

The below is my sample to format the date time:

```
DateFormat('kk:mm').format(time)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You can fix that issue with use `Intl` package, you can add it by
  bellow command `dart pub add intl`.
- For more details you can refer this [link](https://pub.dev/packages/intl/install).

- Now we can format time to your requirements, look at bellow code example,

  ```
  String formatTime() {

   DateTime dateTime = DateTime(2024, 1, 1, 0, 0);


   String formattedTime = DateFormat.Hm().format(dateTime);

   return formattedTime;}
  ```